# Python: Partial String matching in pandas column and retrieve the values from other columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string which is a `file name` as `File_Name =  23092020_indent.xlsx`

Now I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Id   fileKey      fileSource    fileStringLookup
10   rel_ind      sap_indent       indent
20   dm_material   sap_mm          mater
30   dm_vendor     sap_vm          vendor
```

**Objective: Find the `fileKey` and `fileSource` where `fileStringLookup` matches with `file name`.**

Exact match is not possible, hence we may set `regex = True`

for this I am using the following code snippets:

```
if tbl_master_file['fileStringLookup'].str.contains(File_Name,regex=True):
    File_Key = np.where(tbl_master_file['fileStringLookup'].str.contains(File_Name,regex=True),\
                        tbl_master_file['fileKey'],'')
    File_Source = np.where(tbl_master_file['fileStringLookup'].str.contains(File_Name,regex=True),\
                        tbl_master_file['fileSource'],'')
```

But this is not returning any value for `File_Key` and `File_Source`.
Instead I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I investigated further to see whether `df['fileStringLookup'].str.contains(File_Name,regex=True)` is returning any value which is `True`. But it is returning `False`, even for the `Id=10`!!

My desired output:

```
File_Key = 'rel_ind'
File_Source = 'sap_indent'
```

Am I missing out anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is caused because your call to `str.contains` returns a Series of booleans, one for every element of the original Series. Thus, the `if` statement does not know what to check for, as a Series of booleans' truth value is ambiguous.

I would use `pd.iterrows()` inside a function, like :

```
def get_filekey_filesource(filename, df):
   return [{"fileSource": data.loc["fileSource"],
            "fileKey": data.loc["fileKey"]}
           if filename in data.loc["fileStringLookup"]
           else {}
           for index, data in df.iterrows()]
```

As you can see, this will return you a list of dictionnaries where the keys `fileSource`, `fileKey` hold their respective value for rows that match, or an empty dic where matching fails.

This looks far from ideal, but is the best i could come up with. Feedback welcome.

Comment: Once we resolve the issue of `df['fileStringLookup'].str.contains(File_Name, regex =True)`, I think rest of the things will fall in place. We can simply use `np.where` and discard `if` part. Your function may not be necessay then.

Comment: Didnt know about np.where! I think i'll be using this one a lot more than pd.where. Even with np.where, you'll need to iterate over rows somehow, though.

Comment: You dont need to iterate in pandas dataframe.